# multiple Ethernet cards on one mother board

Tags: motherboard, ethernet, network-adapter, pcie

I want to do some maths in terms of the max number of Ethernet adapters a motherboard can take for each port to function without any deterioration.
As I'm planning to plug in multiple Ethernet cards(e.g. four  Quad Port Server Adapter assuming the motherboard has enough slots) and they will be connected to FPGA boards and used for their full bandwidth at all times.That's at least sixteen adapters.  I was wondering if there will be any side effects for such a configuration.

Comment: We need LOTs more information. We need to know the model of the NICs, the motherboard, and the FPGAs. We also need to know what is being transmitted and by what protocols, via what operating system.

Comment: you linked me to an entire product lineup.

Comment: @Adam Wykes  NIC: Intel E1G44ET Gigabit Ethernet Quad Port Server Adapter 1000Mbps[link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106038)                                    motherboard: ASMB-813[link](http://my.advantech.com/Product/Model_Detail.aspx?model_no=ASMB-813)   Protocol used : MAC       whats being transmitted: vector graphics data  
whats connected to the FPGA:88E1111 [link](http://www.marvell.com/transceivers/assets/Marvell-Alaska-Ultra-88E1111-GbE.pdf) 
CPU: i7 5930K/5960X  32GB DDR4

Comment: sorry! had to edit multiple times to get it right @AdamWykes

Comment: OK, and which of those hardwares are you looking for us to make a recommendation on?

Comment: @AdamWykes probably the motherboard. I wanna know if it can take 12 GigE adapters(4-port card x 3) working at full speed. I already know there are enough slots.

Comment: We don't do technical support, but we can recommend a motherboard for you to use. Would you like me to edit your question so that it is asking for a motherboard that can do what you need within a certain budget?

Comment: @AdamWykes Yes. But I'm kinda limited to an advantech motherboard. And budget is not realy an issue.

Comment: OK, you're better off contacting Advantech and asking them for technical support. Having worked with Advantech in my past job, I can tell you that they are pretty good at support. You should close this question as it's not really on-topic.